# ElasticSearch search for part of url

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm working with ElasticSearch 5 and can't find a solution for the following:
I want to search for a string with slashes (part of a url) in a document. But it won't return matching documents.
I've read something that strings with slashes are splitted by ES and that's not what I want for this field. I've tried to set "not_analyzed" on the field with a mapping, but I can't seem to get it to work somehow.

"Create index":
Put http://localhost:9200/test

```
{
    "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 1
    },
    "mappings" : {
        "type1" : {
            "properties" : {
                "field1" : { "type" : "text","index": "not_analyzed" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

"Add document":POST http://localhost:9200/test/type1/

```
{
    "field1" : "this/is/a/url/test"
}
```

"Search document" POST http://localhost:9200/test/type1/_search

```
{
    "size" : 1000,
    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : [{
                    "term" : {
                        "field1" : {
                            "value" : "this/is/a/url/test"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}
```

"The mapping response": GET http://localhost:9200/test/_mapping?pretty

```
{
  "test": {
    "mappings": {
      "type1": {
        "properties": {
          "field1": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a `term` query for getting an exact match is correct. However, your initial mapping is wrong.

```
"type" : "text", "index": "not_analyzed"
```

should be this instead

```
"type": "keyword"
```

(Note: The `keyword` type in ES5 is equivalent to a `not_analyzed` `string` in ES 2.x)

You need to delete your index and re-create it with the corrected mapping. Then your `term` query will work.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect what you need is a [Match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html), not a Terms query. Terms is looking for a single "term"/word and is not breaking down your request with an analyzer.

```
{
    "size" : 1000,
    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : [{
                    "match" : {
                        "field1" :  "this/is/a/url/test"                            
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looked like it worked, but when I add another doc: {
 "field1" : "dit/is/een/url/test/nog/een"
}

that also was returned, instead of only the exact match.

Comment: Depending on what you want you have two options. If the URL is going to be part of a string then you can still use match with the "and" operator. If the field will contain only the URL then @val is correct. I assumed the former case.